# Cyclinder ratio question

Tags: geometry, ratio

So we know that the surface area of two cyclinders are in a ratio of 9:49. Then how do we find the ratio of their height and volume?

I have absolutely no clue on where to begin here because I don't know what the radius is.

Comment: I suppose your question is about cylinders?

Comment: @Bernard yes it is

Comment: Are the cylinders similar?

Comment: @A.Goodier yes they are similar

Comment: Then the ratio of heights is just $\sqrt{9}:\sqrt{49}=3:7$ and the ratio of volumes is $3^3:7^3$.

Comment: @A.Goodier Can you possibly explain your solution to me?

Comment: This is just length/area/volume scale factor - e.g. see some of the examples [here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/z9wjng8/revision/4)

Answer (score 0):

For any similar solids, if the similarity ratio is $k$, the ratio of their surfaces is $k^2$ and the ratio of their volumes is $k^3$.